# Finding fitness/objective function for evaluation of intermediatory solutions

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics

Each WorkItem has how work is distributed across week, i.e amount of hours work for each day of week.

```
eg. WeekItemA
   Monday    100
   Tuesday   300
   Wednesday 500
   Thursday  100 
   Friday    200
```

We also have maximum work which can be done per day, capacity of each day.

```
eg. MaxCapacity
   Monday    1500
   Tuesday   1500
   Wednesday 2000
   Thursday  1500
   Friday    1500
```

Given a list of WorkItem. Need to find subset of given work items which should be selected to reach capacity of each day .

What would be the best way to solve above problem.

I am currently thinking of doing this greedily i.e selecting one of the work item at each step until reaching max capacity. At each step selecting the next best possible. 
But need to have objective function which can evaluate each selection. Unable to decide what would be the best objective function to evaluate it.

Comment: Have you read much about the [Multidimensional Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multi-dimensional_knapsack_problem)?